# Unequal misclassification costs in python/sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I wonder if there is a way to specify custom cost function in sklearn/python?
My real problem has 7 different classes, but to make it more clear lets assume that I want to specify different cost for misclassification for a problem with 3 different classes and I am mainly interested that my model will properly distinguish between class 1 and class 3.

- if observation has class 1 and model predicts class 1, penalty is 0 (correct classification)
- if observation has class 1 and model predicts class 2, penalty is 1
- if point has class 1 and model predicts class 3, penalty is 2

---

- if point has class 2 and model predicts class 2, penalty is 0 (correct classification)
- if point has class 2 and model predicts class 3, penalty is 1
- if point has class 2 and model predicts class 1, penalty is 1

---

- if point has class 3 and model predicts class 3, penalty is 0 (correct classification)
- if point has class 3 and model predicts class 2, penalty is 1
- if point has class 3 and model predicts class 1, penalty is 2

---

So the penalty matrix would look as follows:

```
        Class 1  Class 2  Class 3
Class 1   0        1        2
Class 2   1        0        1
Class 3   2        1        0
```

I assume that the 'class_weight' parameter in sklearn does something similar but accepts a dictionary rather than a matrix. Passing class_weight = {1:2,1:1,1:2} would just increase the weight for misclassifying class 1 and class 3, I ,however, want my model get a larger penalty specifically when it chooses class 1 and true class is class 3 and vice versa.

Is it possible to do something like this in sklearn? May be some other libraries/learning algorithms allow for unequal misclassification cost?

Answer (score 2):

First, in sklearn there is no way to train a model using custom loss. However, you can [implement your own evaluation function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720878/customize-loss-function-sklearn) and adjust hyperparameters of your model to optimize this metric.

Second, you can optimize any custom loss with neural networks, [for example, using Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961428/make-a-custom-loss-function-in-keras). But for this purpose, your function should be smooth. The first thing that comes to mind is weighted cross-entropy. In [this discussion](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2115), people are playing with implementations of this function.

Third, the structure of your own problem suggests that **order** of class labels is what really matters. If this is the case, you could try ordered logistic regression (an [example](http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2013/logistic-ordinal-regression/) of its implementation).

Moreover, in your problem the cost is precisely `sum(abs(predicted-fact))`. So if you don't need probabilistic prediction, you can simply use a regressor that optimizes MAE (e.g. SGDRegressor with 'epsilon_insensitive' loss or DecisionTreeRegressor with mae criterion). After solving the regression, you need only to find the thresholds that optimize your cost function.

Comment: Why not train a classifier and after optimize a custom score function?